# Why is this Icefaces component not allowing my application to work?

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I have a `index.xhtml` page listing books. Once a book is clicked it goes to `book.xhtml` to show the particular details of that book. It works. However for my project im meant to use Icefaces. When I add an Iceface component, a `ice:panelTabSet`, to `book.xhtml` clicking the links on the `index.xhtml` wont redirect to `book.xhtml` anymore. Could anyone shed any light on this?

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>BookShop</title>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form>
       <ul>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bookCatelogBean.books}" var="book">
        <li>
            <h:commandLink action="bookDetails">#{book.title}
                <f:param name="id" value="#{book.id}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

**book.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">
    <h:head>
        <title>BookShop</title>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        #{book.title}

        <h:graphicImage id="image1" value="#{book.coverImage}" /> 

        #{book.description}

        <ice:panelTabSet styleClass="tabSet" tabPlacement="bottom" align="right">
            <ice:panelTab label="label1"> 
                <ice:outputText value="Label" />
            </ice:panelTab>
            <ice:panelTab label="label2"> 
                <ice:outputText value="Label2" />
            </ice:panelTab>
            <ice:panelTab label="label3">
                <ice:outputText value="Label3" /> 
            </ice:panelTab>
        </ice:panelTabSet>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using Facelets, not JSP, so please don't add JSP tag. I've removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h:commandLink>` doesn't seem to point to any existing page. You've set it to `bookDetails`, but the target view ID is `book` (from `book.xhtml`). You also don't need POST here, it would only make the links uncrawlable by searchbots and unbookmarkable by endusers.

Use `<h:link>` instead and set its `outcome` to `book` instead of `bookDetails`.

```html
<h:link value="#{book.title}" outcome="book">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{book.id}" />
</h:link>
```

Don't forget to remove the `<h:form>`.